# disallow remove for last value in multi select options - select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

The selected `option` is from database. Now i want, i can remove any two value but last value can't be removed. I have tried `disabled: true` but don't know how can i restrict to not delete last name. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    
<select id="test" multiple style="width:250px" name="lastname">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you. Refer [official documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) for more of such events.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
    });
    $('#test').on("select2:unselecting", function (e) {
      if($(this).val().length === 1) {
        alert("You cannot remove last value");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    
<select id="test" multiple style="width:250px" name="lastname">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I already try some code, and this might work well

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let prevVal = $('#test').val();
$("#test").select2({
  tags: true,
  allowClear: false,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
}).on("change", function (e) { 
    if($("#test").val() !== null){
        prevVal = $('#test').val();
    }
    else{
        $('#test').val(prevVal)
        $('#test').trigger('change.select2')
    }
});});
```